# How to repeat a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, dataframe, repeat

This is my DataFrame that should be repeated for 5 times:

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':2}, index = range(1))
>>> x
   a  b
0  1  2
```

I want to have the result like this:

```
>>> x.append(x).append(x).append(x)
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
```

But there must be a smarter way than appending 4 times. Actually the DataFrame I’m working on should be repeated 50 times.

I haven't found anything practical, including those like `np.repeat` ---- it just doesn't work on a DataFrame.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can use the `concat` function:

```
In [13]: pd.concat([x]*5)
Out[13]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
```

If you only want to repeat the values and not the index, you can do:

```
In [14]: pd.concat([x]*5, ignore_index=True)
Out[14]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  1  2
```

Answer (score 36):

I think it's cleaner/faster to use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) nowadays:

```
In [11]: np.full(3, 0)
Out[11]: array([0, 0, 0])

In [12]: x.iloc[np.full(3, 0)]
Out[12]:
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
```

More generally, you can use [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) or [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [23]: np.tile(np.arange(len(df)), 3)
Out[23]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])

In [24]: np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), 3)
Out[24]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

In [25]: df.iloc[np.tile(np.arange(len(df)), 3)]
Out[25]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [26]: df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), 3)]
Out[26]:
   A  B
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
1  3  4
1  3  4
1  3  4
```

Note: This will work with non-integer indexed DataFrames (and Series).

Comment: Why is this cleaner than other solutions?

Comment: this is a better solution

Comment: This is so much faster than the currently accepted answer

Answer (score 11):

Try using [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(x.to_numpy(), 5, axis=0), columns=x.columns)
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  1  2
```

Comment: This is at least ~2x faster than pd.concat

Comment: this is the answer i wanted. fast and neat and easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

I would generally not repeat and/or append, unless your problem really makes it necessary - it is highly inefficiently and *typically* comes from not understanding the proper way to attack a problem.

I don't know your exact use case, but if you have your values stored as

```
values = array(1, 2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=arange(0,50),  columns=['a', 'b'])
df2[['a', 'b']] = values
```

will do the job. Perhaps you want to better explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a data frame which lacks one line for each identifier. I wanna insert this line in it, so what Im gonna do is  to repeat this line for N times, and append it to the original data frame, then resort it.

Answer (score 2):

Append should work too:

```
In [589]: x = pd.DataFrame({'a':1,'b':2},index = range(1))

In [590]: x
Out[590]: 
   a  b
0  1  2

In [591]: x.append([x]*5, ignore_index=True) #Ignores the index as per your need
Out[591]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  1  2
5  1  2

In [592]: x.append([x]*5)
Out[592]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
0  1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `numpy`, we could also use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) (or [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)):

```
x.loc[x.index.repeat(5)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
x.reindex(x.index.repeat(5)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
4  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply by row-lambda is a universal approach in my opinion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

df.apply(lambda row: row.repeat(2), axis=0) #.reset_index()

Out[1]: 
    A   B
0   1   2
0   1   2
1   3   4
1   3   4
```