# Pandas/Numpy: Fastest way to create a ladder?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
    color     cost    temp
0   blue      12.0    80.4   
1    red       8.1    81.2 
2   pink      24.5    83.5
```

and I want to create a "ladder" or a "range" of costs for every row at 50 cent increments, from $0.50 below the current cost to $0.50 above the current cost. My current code is similar to the follow:

```
incremented_prices = []

df['original_idx'] = df.index # To know it's original label

for row in df.iterrows():
    current_price = row['cost']
    more_costs    = numpy.arange(current_price-1, current_price+1, step=0.5)

    for cost in more_costs:
        row_c = row.copy()
        row_c['cost'] = cost
        incremented_prices.append(row_c)

df_incremented = pandas.concat(incremented_prices)
```

And this code will produce a DataFrame like:

```
    color     cost    temp  original_idx
0   blue      11.5    80.4            0
1   blue      12.0    80.4            0 
2   blue      12.5    80.4            0  
3    red       7.6    81.2            1 
4    red       8.1    81.2            1 
5    red       8.6    81.2            1 
6   pink      24.0    83.5            2
7   pink      24.5    83.5            2
8   pink      25.0    83.5            2
```

In the real problem, I will make ranges from -$50.00 to $50.00 and I find this really slow, is there some faster vectorized way?

Comment: You could also rephrase the question as follows: how do I create a DF which has each row of my original DF repeated N times? Then, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23887881/1258041) may be useful.

Comment: @Lev That would be part of it, but for each row I need a different price which is based on the original price +/- a certain amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try recreate a data frame with `numpy.repeat`:

```
cost_steps = pd.np.arange(-0.5, 0.51, 0.5)
repeats = cost_steps.size   

pd.DataFrame(dict(
    color = pd.np.repeat(df.color.values, repeats),
    # here is a vectorized method to calculate the costs with all steps added with broadcasting
    cost = (df.cost.values[:, None] + cost_steps).ravel(),
    temp = pd.np.repeat(df.temp.values, repeats),
    original_idx = pd.np.repeat(df.index.values, repeats)
    ))
```

[image]

*Update* for more columns:

```
df1 = df.rename_axis("original_idx").reset_index()
cost_steps = pd.np.arange(-0.5, 0.51, 0.5)
repeats = cost_steps.size   

pd.DataFrame(pd.np.hstack((pd.np.repeat(df1.drop("cost", 1).values, repeats, axis=0),
                          (df1.cost[:, None] + cost_steps).reshape(-1, 1))),
             columns=df1.columns.drop("cost").tolist()+["cost"])
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I want, but I have like 500 columns so I wouldn't want to type out each column. Is there a way to combine your answer with a dataframe that has 500 columns

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy intialization based approach -

```
increments = 0.5*np.arange(-1,2) # Edit the increments here

names = np.append(df.columns, 'original_idx')

M,N = df.shape
vals = df.values

cost_col_idx = (names == 'cost').argmax()

n = len(increments)
shp = (M,n,N+1)
b = np.empty(shp,dtype=object)
b[...,:-1] = vals[:,None]
b[...,-1] = np.arange(M)[:,None]
b[...,cost_col_idx] = vals[:,cost_col_idx].astype(float)[:,None] + increments
b.shape = (-1,N+1)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=names)
```

To make the increments go from `-50` to `+50` with increments of `0.5`, use :

```
increments = 0.5*np.arange(-100,101)
```

Sample run -

```
In [200]: df
Out[200]: 
  color  cost  temp  newcol
0  blue  12.0  80.4   mango
1   red   8.1  81.2  banana
2  pink  24.5  83.5   apple

In [201]: df_out
Out[201]: 
  color  cost  temp  newcol original_idx
0  blue  11.5  80.4   mango            0
1  blue    12  80.4   mango            0
2  blue  12.5  80.4   mango            0
3   red   7.6  81.2  banana            1
4   red   8.1  81.2  banana            1
5   red   8.6  81.2  banana            1
6  pink    24  83.5   apple            2
7  pink  24.5  83.5   apple            2
8  pink    25  83.5   apple            2
```