# How can I duplicate a value or string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, duplicates, repeat

I have the a pandas columns containing multiple strings. I want all these strings to be duplicated 3 times.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['a','b','c']),
```

Desired output:

```
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

I want to transform this table so it looks like this:

```
   0
0  a
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  b
5  b
6  c
7  c
8  c
```

I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

Anything will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat Pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23887956/13552470)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
df[0].repeat(3).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Out:

```
0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
4    b
5    b
6    c
7    c
8    c
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df]*3).sort_values(0)`

Comment: I mean, OP had a unique index.  `pd.concat([df]*3).sort_values(0)` gives me `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `repeat` + `reindex`:

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(3))
Out[105]: 
   0
0  a
0  a
0  a
1  b
1  b
1  b
2  c
2  c
2  c
```

Or `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*3)
```