# Pandas concat function with count assigned for each iteration

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, count, concatenation

At the replication of a dataframe using `concat` with index (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23887956/17508643)), is there a way I can assign a count variable for each iteration in column c (where column c is the count variable)?

Orig df:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

df replicated with `pd.concat[df]*5` and with an additional Column c:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |

This is a multi-row dataframe where the count variable would have to be applied to multiple rows.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
N = 5
new_df = pd.concat([df] * N)
new_df['c'] = np.repeat(np.arange(N), df.shape[0]) + 1
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  1
1  2  3  1
0  1  2  2
1  2  3  2
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  3
0  1  2  4
1  2  3  4
0  1  2  5
1  2  3  5
```